# Sitecore content editor deep linking

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore 6, is there a way to deep link into the content editor? I'd like to bookmark something like

`https://mysite.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20editor.aspx?item=/sitecore/Content/Data/foo`

And have that bookmark go directly to that item in the content editor.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to use the **fo** parameter and item id instead of path, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?fo={4142d44b-2237-4795-b219-85e70420fced}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ro` QueryString parameter works, somewhat; for example: `https://mysite.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20editor.aspx?ro=/sitecore/Content/Data/foo` works, except it puts that item at the root of the content editor.

Anyone know how to show the whole tree with the specified item open?